# Styling points based on letter in field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, fields-attributes, style

I am trying to do different symbols for my data in QGIS the only different between my points is the letter 'W' or 'D'. I want that each point will get a different color or shape to vizualize that on the map.

That how the attribute table looks like:

[image: that how its organize]

I try to use this code:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "NAME" LIKE 'W' THEN 'square'
    WHEN "NAME" ILIKE 'W' THEN 'circle'
END
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: If you want the two styles in a legend, it will be much easier using rule based styling instead of overriding the shape/color

Comment: That's what `regexp_match()` is there for.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9):

[`LIKE`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#operators) without a placeholder will not match much. You have to use the "`%`" sign to denote where anything else might appear next to the character(s) you specify.

For example `LIKE '%W` will match anything that ends with an uppercase "W".

Caveat: `LIKE` is slow, consider using `right()` instead: `right("NAME", 1) = 'W'`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your 'W' or 'D' is always the last letter of your `"Name"`-string this should work:

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN right("NAME", 1) = 'W' THEN 'square' 
    WHEN right("NAME", 1) = 'D' THEN 'circle'
    ELSE ''
END
```

Answer (score 5):

As was mentioned by @Erik in his comment, it is efficient to use the [`regexp_match()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#regexp-match) function.

Use the following expression:

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN regexp_match("NAME", 'W') THEN 'square' 
    WHEN regexp_match("NAME", 'B') THEN 'circle'
    ELSE ''
END
```